# Instantaneous Current (Inrush) Calculation

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inrush-current

How is the instantaneous (inrush) current calculated for the capacitor in this circuit?

[image]

Both Falstad Circuit Simulator and LTSpice give the same answer for inrush current (500 uA).

LTSpice
[image]

Falstad Circuit Simulator
[image]

How does this get calculated?

Comment: Also, I know that once the switch closes the inductor appears as an open and the capacitor appears as a short.  Any leakage current through the inductor should pass through the capacitor.  Is the 500 uA current value the inductor leakage current or is there actually a calculation for the inrush current?

Comment: Looks like the method is to calculate the step response for the circuit.  From what I've seen, this is done via Laplace Transform and/or second order equations.  Is this the right track?

Comment: It's not a straightforward algebraic equation if that's what you're hoping.    There are ways to calculate it.  But honestly, you've already performed the easiest one  ;)   (Simulate it)

Comment: To calculate this by hand, you do KVL but you will end up with a differential equation due to the derivatives and integrals in the capacitor and inductor terms. There are multiple methods to solve the differential equation, but Laplace transforms are the easiest.

Comment: Search this website for "RLC differential equation" and you will come up with at least a few examples. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480405/calculating-differential-equation-rlc-circuit

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I was really banging my head on this!  Glad to know that differential equations and simulation is the way to go for solving these.

Comment: @mrbean That should help out. One thing to take note of is that the series resistor (in series with the inductance) obviously doesn't have much impact. Your peak current only implies at most 2.5 mV drop across it. So you could simplify your analysis by just removing it. This still leaves the other resistor (in parallel with the capacitor.) And that one will definitely impact the moment when the peak is reached -- a LOT because it is so conductive. Even a few mV across it will be an issue.

Comment: @mrbean If you eliminate that parallel resistor, computing the moment when the peak occurs is trivial. It's just \$t=\frac{\pi}2\,\sqrt{L\,C}\$. Or at about 5 ms in time. But the peak will be a lot higher, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRRBfV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_2\$:

$$\text{V}_2=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag4$$

Using \$(2)\$, we can see that:

$$\text{I}_3=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_4\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag5$$

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_2=\text{sL}\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\tag7$$
- The input voltage is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}}{\displaystyle\text{s}}\tag8$$

So, we get:

$$\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}}{\displaystyle\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_1+\text{sL}\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{sL}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\right)}\tag9$$

Now, when we use inverse Laplace transform (using your values) we can see:

$$\text{I}_3\left(t\right)=\frac{\displaystyle2 e^{-\frac{\displaystyle5}{\displaystyle2} \left(\displaystyle\sqrt{15976001}+4001\right)\displaystyle t} \left(e^{\displaystyle5 \sqrt{15976001} t}-1\right)}{\displaystyle\sqrt{15976001}}\tag{10}$$

Plotting that, gives:

[image]

The maximum occurs when:

$$\hat{t}=\frac{\displaystyle2 \text{arccoth}\left(\frac{\displaystyle4001}{\displaystyle\sqrt{15976001}}\right)}{\displaystyle5 \sqrt{15976001}}\approx0.000380305\space\text{s}\tag{11}$$

And at that time \$\$ we have a current of:

$$\text{I}_3\left(\hat{t}\right)\approx0.000498226\space\text{A}\tag{12}$$

---

Using Mathematica I found a way of finding the time when the maximum occurs:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
R2 = s*L;
R3 = 1/(s*c);
Vi = u/s;
R1 = ;
R4 = ;
u = ;
L = ;
c = ;
\[Tau] = FullSimplify[
   Solve[{D[
       FullSimplify[
        InverseLaplaceTransform[
         I3 /. FullSimplify[
             Solve[{I1 == I3 + I4, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
               I1 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I3 == V2/R3, I4 == V2/R4}, {I1, I3,
                I4, V1, V2}]][[1]][[2]], s, t]], t] == 0, t > 0}, t]];
Flatten[\[Tau]] && Flatten[N[\[Tau]]]
```

Comment: Very nicely arranged, Jan! It's approachable for anyone. +1

Comment: @jonk thank you very much!!

Comment: It was really a wonderful approach!! I loved the simple and accessible way you started out, and then the way to segued into transitioning into Laplace replacements, and the use of the inverse transform. It was a beautiful thing to see. And it teaches how useful and yet also simple, once you get comfortable with the ideas, that Laplace approaches are towards differential equations. You really brought it. I loved it! I hope you stick around and continue to share your perspective and vision.

Comment: @jonk again thank you so so much, I hope that I can help more people here!

Comment: I've no doubt of it, Jan!! I'm so glad to see you here. I can't express that enough. It's the kind of vision that you can share with others that will make differences. I very much hope to see more of you here, helping others see as you do. I think your vision is one of crystal clarity and beauty. It just "sings" in my mind. Some others, those who can hear, will hear that melody well. Best wishes!!

Comment: @jonk Thank you for those kind words, I really appreciate it! I am trying to answer to questions in a very simple and rigorous way, and I am very happy to see that you also have that vision!

Comment: It's sometimes hard to pass along visions. When I saw your approach I couldn't think of a better way. It was just ... really good. I don't think I could have done better. Likely, I'd have done a little worse to be honest. And that matters. We have our visions. But we cannot always present it as best we might. And having you here adds yet another who may provide those insights, in a novel and still better way, to help others grasp and accumulate the ways we see the world. We learn from our betters, not for their conclusions so much, but for how they "see the world." You offer something here.

Comment: @jonk I totally agree! I do not know what to say to all these kind words you're writing here, I am trying to do my best and seeing someone who appreciates it so much really feels good. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: I'm just glad to see you, to recognize your mind, to hear your thoughts sing in my mind. Keep it up and offer yourself to others. That's enough. It's more than enough.