# Find voltage across capacitor

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, capacitor, transient

[image: t][image: I want to see ode I don’t know how to write it]

[image]

I want to see code. I don’t know how to write it.

Comment: Show us your progress. If you can't write anything down, then turn the inductor and capacitor into resistors named \$Z_L\$ and \$Z_C\$ and show us our equations for that. Then we can substitute the capacitor and inductor back in later. If you can't even write the loop equations for that, then you need to go do more studying because your issues are more fundamental than this circuit.

Comment: @DKNguyen  I can’t simplify the loop equation in term of V_c

Comment: @ThomasEdison -1 for having two different (hand drawn!) schematics in your question which causes ambiguity. Update your question and include a proper schematic.

Comment: Here is something that might help.  Some of the calculations will carry over into the circuit that you are trying to solve.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517094/instantaneous-current-inrush-calculation

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I've found a mistake in one of your equations, so I'll use a corrected version of it in this answer.

First, let's write down our system of differential-algebraic equations
$$
V_C = -3I_1 \tag{1} \label{1}\\
$$
$$
V_C = 6I_L + L\frac{\mathrm{d}I_L}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{2} \label{2}\\
$$
$$
I_C = C\frac{\mathrm{d}V_C}{\mathrm{d}t} \tag{3} \label{3}\\
$$
$$
I_C + I_L - I_1 = 0 \tag{4} \label{4}
$$
Notice that the right hand side of equation \eqref{1} is multiplied by \$-1\$ compared to your original equation.

The way this system is set up, solving for \$V_C\$ is a little tricky, but we've got options:

1. The most obvious solution is to solve for \$I_L\$ then work our way back to \$V_C\$.

Substitute the time derivative of \eqref{2} in \eqref{3} so you can express \$I_C\$ in terms of \$I_L\$. Substitute \eqref{2} in \eqref{1} and, using \eqref{4} and the previous result, find the second-order ODE for \$I_L\$. Solve it and use \eqref{2} to find \$V_C\$.

2. Alternatively, you can manipulate the system's equations to eliminate \$I_L\$ and solve it directly for \$V_C\$.

Substitute \eqref{4} in \eqref{1}, using \eqref{3}, to find \$I_L\$ in terms of \$V_C\$ and its derivative \$\mathrm{d}V_C/\mathrm{d}t\$. Substitute the previous result and its derivative in \eqref{2} to find the second-order ODE for \$V_C\$.

3. Rewriting the differential equations \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} in differential operator (\$\boldsymbol{D}\$) notation, the process in option 2 can be done algebraically.

Equation \eqref{2} becomes
$$
\tag{5} \label{5} V_C = 6I_L + L\boldsymbol{D}I_L = (6 + L\boldsymbol{D})I_L\\
I_L = \frac{V_C}{6 + L\boldsymbol{D}}
$$
and equation \eqref{3} is expressed as
$$
\tag{6} \label{6} I_C = C\boldsymbol{D}V_C.
$$

Applying \eqref{5} and \eqref{6} in \eqref{4}
$$
\tag{7} \label{7} I_1 = C\boldsymbol{D}V_C + \frac{V_C}{6 + L\boldsymbol{D}} = \frac{LC\boldsymbol{D}^2 + 6C\boldsymbol{D} + 1}{6 + L\boldsymbol{D}}V_C
$$

Finally, plugging \eqref{7} into \eqref{1}
$$
\tag{8} \label{8} -(6 + L\boldsymbol{D})V_C = (3LC\boldsymbol{D}^2 + 18C\boldsymbol{D} + 3)V_C\\
[3LC\boldsymbol{D}^2 + (18C + L)\boldsymbol{D} + 9]V_C = 0
$$
Note that in the previous step, even though we have \$V_C\$ on both sides of the equation, we can't cancel it out because **a)** we'd be eliminating the only remaining variable and **b)** we'd be left with an "equation" in terms of the operator \$\boldsymbol{D}\$, however, the differential operator is a notation convenience and, as such, only makes sense when associated with a variable.

Reverting \eqref{8} back to conventional notation we have the ODE
$$
3LC\frac{\mathrm{d}^2V_C}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + (18C + L)\frac{\mathrm{d}V_C}{\mathrm{d}t} + 9V_C = 0.
$$

Solve for \$V_C\$ as usual.

Comment: Hrm, yeah. Making Vc the common link between both your loop equations make it real easy to go Vc = Loop 1 = Loop 2 which eliminates Vc. But it also makes it so you have to find Vc in a roundabout manner if that's your goal. Doing a supermesh (one loop overlapping a smaller inner loop) should get around this. My eyes are glazing over looking at the piece of paper because I have to solve everything first just to get things in terms of Vc.

Comment: One trick that has served me well recently is to, instead of setting up equations in terms loop currents and node voltages, set up equations in terms of capacitor voltages and inductor currents

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ9Qf4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can see that:

$$\displaystyle\text{I}_3\left(t\right)=\text{I}_1\left(t\right)+\text{I}_2\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Using the current and voltage relations in the components we can write:

$$
\displaystyle\begin{cases}
\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\text{I}_1\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_1\\
\\
\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=\text{I}_2\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}_2\\
\\
\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=\text{I}_2'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\\
\\
\text{I}_3\left(t\right)=\left(0-\text{V}_1'\left(t\right)\right)\cdot\text{C}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using your values, you will find that the voltage across the capacitor is given by:

$$\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\frac{36}{5} e^{-3 t} \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{3} t\right)-\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\sqrt{3} t\right)\right)\tag3$$

---

I used Mathematica to solve this:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
R1 = 3;
R2 = 6;
L = 3;
c = 1/12;
u = 36/5;
k = 6/5;
FullSimplify[
 DSolve[{Subscript[i, 3][t] == 
    Subscript[i, 1][t] + Subscript[i, 2][t], 
   Subscript[v, 1][t] == Subscript[i, 1][t]*R1, 
   Subscript[v, 1][t] - Subscript[v, 2][t] == Subscript[i, 2][t]*R2, 
   Subscript[v, 2][t] == Subscript[i, 2]'[t]*L, 
   Subscript[i, 3][t] == (0 - Subscript[v, 1]'[t])*c, 
   Subscript[v, 1][0] == u, 
   Subscript[i, 2][0] == k}, {Subscript[i, 1][t], Subscript[i, 2][t], 
   Subscript[i, 3][t], Subscript[v, 1][t], Subscript[v, 2][t]}, {t}]]

Out[1]={{Subscript[i, 1][t] -> 
   12/5 E^(-3 t) (Cos[Sqrt[3] t] - Sqrt[3] Sin[Sqrt[3] t]), 
  Subscript[i, 2][t] -> 
   6/5 E^(-3 t) (Cos[Sqrt[3] t] + Sqrt[3] Sin[Sqrt[3] t]), 
  Subscript[i, 3][
    t] -> -(6/5)
      E^(-3 t) (-3 Cos[Sqrt[3] t] + Sqrt[3] Sin[Sqrt[3] t]), 
  Subscript[v, 1][t] -> 
   36/5 E^(-3 t) (Cos[Sqrt[3] t] - Sqrt[3] Sin[Sqrt[3] t]), 
  Subscript[v, 2][t] -> -(72/5) Sqrt[3] E^(-3 t) Sin[Sqrt[3] t]}}
```

Comment: I don't see how the initial conditions lead to contradiction. The math checked out in my end

Comment: @VictorSouza you're right, I edited my answer.

Comment: R1 should be \$3 \ \Omega\$

Comment: @VictorSouza Sorry, edited my answer.

Comment: That solution can also be written as a single cosine with phase \$\pi/3\$ times the decaying exponential